# Is there a "groupby" query in wordpress REST api?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api

Does wordpress rest api have groupby SQL query?

Example:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[meta_key]=age&filter[groupby]=25
```

Comment: You can refer meta query using rest API of WordPress : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271877/how-to-do-a-meta-query-using-rest-api-in-wordpress-4-7

Answer (score 0):

Since Wordpress 4.7, the WP Rest API does not support `filter`.

So you can either use [WP Rest Filter plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/rest-filter) or need to create you custom endpoint with custom functionality.